# JPA one to one relation not added

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa, one-to-one

I have a two tables in database in relation one to one:

```
CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `toproject`.`osoby` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
  `imie` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL ,
  `nazwisko` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL ,
  `pesel` VARCHAR(11) NOT NULL ,
  `telefon` VARCHAR(45) NULL ,
  `pensja` VARCHAR(45) NULL ,
  `typ` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL ,
  `stanowisko_id` INT NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`) ,
  UNIQUE INDEX `pesel_UNIQUE` (`pesel` ASC) ,
  INDEX `fk_osoby_stanowiska_idx` (`stanowisko_id` ASC) ,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_osoby_stanowiska`
    FOREIGN KEY (`stanowisko_id` )
    REFERENCES `toproject`.`stanowiska` (`id` )
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;

CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `toproject`.`adresy` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `ulica` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL ,
  `miejscowosc` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL ,
  INDEX `fk_adres_osoby1_idx` (`id` ASC) ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`) ,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_adres_osoby1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`id` )
    REFERENCES `toproject`.`osoby` (`id` )
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

I must using to this `@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)` I write that Java entity class:

Head class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "osoby")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name="typ", discriminatorType=DiscriminatorType.STRING)
public class Osoba implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Integer id;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 1, max = 45)
    @Column(name = "imie")
    private String imie;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 1, max = 45)
    @Column(name = "nazwisko")
    private String nazwisko;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 1, max = 11)
    @Column(name = "pesel")
    private String pesel;
```

Client class:

```
@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue(value = "Klient")
public class Klient extends Osoba {

    @Size(max = 45)
    @Column(name = "telefon")
    private String telefon;
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "osobyId")
    private Collection<Zamowienie> zamowienieCollection;
    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "klient")
    private Adres adres;
```

Adress Entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "adresy")
public class Adres implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Integer id;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 1, max = 45)
    @Column(name = "ulica")
    private String ulica;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 1, max = 45)
    @Column(name = "miejscowosc")
    private String miejscowosc;
    @JoinColumn(name = "id", referencedColumnName = "id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    @OneToOne(optional = false)
    private Klient klient;
```

I have a klientMB which adds the person and the address

```
@ManagedBean
@RequestScoped
public class KlientMB {

    @EJB
    private KlientDaoLocal klientDao;
    private Klient klient;

    public KlientMB() {
    }

    public Klient getKlient() {
        if (klient == null) {
            klient = new Klient();
            Adres adres = new Adres();
            klient.setAdres(adres);
            adres.setOsoba(klient);
        }
        return klient;
    }

    public void setKlient(Klient klient) {
        this.klient = klient;
    }

    public String createKlient() {
        klientDao.create(klient);
        return "klienci.xhtml?faces-redirect=true";

    }
```

but when i try added a Klient i have this error:

> javax.faces.el.EvaluationException: javax.ejb.EJBException
>       at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:102)
>       at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:102)
>       at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:315)
>       at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:794)
>       at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1259)
>       at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
>       at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
>       at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118)
>       at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:593)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1550)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:281)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:655)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:595)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:161)
>       at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:331)
>       at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:231)
>       at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$AdapterCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:317)
>       at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:195)
>       at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:860)
>       at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:757)
>       at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1056)
>       at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:229)
>       at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
>       at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
>       at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
>       at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
>       at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
>       at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
>       at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
>       at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
>       at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
>   Caused by: javax.ejb.EJBException
>       at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.processSystemException(BaseContainer.java:5215)
>       at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.completeNewTx(BaseContainer.java:5113)
>       at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.postInvokeTx(BaseContainer.java:4901)
>       at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.postInvoke(BaseContainer.java:2045)
>       at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.postInvoke(BaseContainer.java:1994)
>       at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.java:222)
>       at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.java:89)
>       at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy177.create(Unknown Source)
>       at pl.ear.mb.KlientMB.createKlient(KlientMB.java:45)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
>       at javax.el.BeanELResolver.invokeMethod(BeanELResolver.java:779)
>       at javax.el.BeanELResolver.invoke(BeanELResolver.java:528)
>       at javax.el.CompositeELResolver.invoke(CompositeELResolver.java:257)
>       at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:248)
>       at com.sun.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:302)
>       at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:105)
>       at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:88)
>       ... 32 more
>   Caused by: javax.persistence.EntityExistsException: org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not insert: [pl.ear.model.Adres]
>       at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.throwPersistenceException(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:612)
>       at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.persist(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:226)
>       at com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.EntityManagerWrapper.persist(EntityManagerWrapper.java:269)
>       at pl.ear.dao.KlientDao.create(KlientDao.java:26)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
>       at org.glassfish.ejb.security.application.EJBSecurityManager.runMethod(EJBSecurityManager.java:1052)
>       at org.glassfish.ejb.security.application.EJBSecurityManager.invoke(EJBSecurityManager.java:1124)
>       at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.invokeBeanMethod(BaseContainer.java:5388)
>       at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.invokeBeanMethod(EjbInvocation.java:619)
>       at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:800)
>       at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.proceed(EjbInvocation.java:571)
>       at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.SystemInterceptorProxy.doAround(SystemInterceptorProxy.java:162)
>       at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.SystemInterceptorProxy.aroundInvoke(SystemInterceptorProxy.java:144)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
>       at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeInterceptor.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:861)
>       at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:800)
>       at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.InterceptorManager.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:370)
>       at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.__intercept(BaseContainer.java:5360)
>       at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.intercept(BaseContainer.java:5348)
>       at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.java:214)
>       ... 46 more
>   Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not insert: [pl.ear.model.Adres]
>       at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:71)
>       at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:43)
>       at org.hibernate.id.insert.AbstractReturningDelegate.performInsert(AbstractReturningDelegate.java:40)
>       at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2158)
>       at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2638)
>       at org.hibernate.action.EntityIdentityInsertAction.execute(EntityIdentityInsertAction.java:48)
>       at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:250)
>       at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:298)
>       at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:181)
>       at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:107)
>       at org.hibernate.ejb.event.EJB3PersistEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(EJB3PersistEventListener.java:49)
>       at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultPersistEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:131)
>       at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:87)
>       at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.firePersist(SessionImpl.java:609)
>       at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:601)
>       at org.hibernate.engine.EJB3CascadingAction$1.cascade(EJB3CascadingAction.java:30)
>       at org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascadeToOne(Cascade.java:268)
>       at org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascadeAssociation(Cascade.java:216)
>       at org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascadeProperty(Cascade.java:169)
>       at org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascade(Cascade.java:130)
>       at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.cascadeAfterSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:456)
>       at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:334)
>       at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:181)
>       at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:107)
>       at org.hibernate.ejb.event.EJB3PersistEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(EJB3PersistEventListener.java:49)
>       at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultPersistEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:131)
>       at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:87)
>       at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:38)
>       at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.firePersist(SessionImpl.java:618)
>       at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:592)
>       at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:596)
>       at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.persist(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:220)
>       ... 70 more
>   Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`toproject`.`adresy`, CONSTRAINT `FKAB3C9E7C7D93F9AD` FOREIGN KEY (`id`) REFERENCES `osoby` (`id`))
>       at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
>       at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
>       at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:386)
>       at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1041)
>       at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4187)
>       at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4119)
>       at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2570)
>       at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2731)
>       at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2815)
>       at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2155)
>       at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2458)
>       at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2375)
>       at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2359)
>       at org.hibernate.id.IdentityGenerator$GetGeneratedKeysDelegate.executeAndExtract(IdentityGenerator.java:73)
>       at org.hibernate.id.insert.AbstractReturningDelegate.performInsert(AbstractReturningDelegate.java:33)
>       ... 99 more

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you are using the `id` (primary key) column from `toproject.adresy` table as the foreign key to connect to the `toproject.osoby`. You should introduce a new column(e.g. osoby_id) as the foreign key column to connect to the `toproject.osoby`. 
What is currently happening is that, the id of the `Adres` table is being used to find a record in the `Osoby` table and there is none there.